# Using ajax to check something about variable in Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I would like to know a Rails equivalent for something I am used to do using PHP.

When checking if a user input meets certain criteria, I usually make some Ajax calls using javascript to a php page that processes the data and echo a json data. I then use the json data to construct appropriate behaviors.

For instance, let's assume a user submitted a postcode and I want to run some checks on the postcode on server side. I would do something like this in js:

```
// This is what the user submitted
var postcode = $("#postcode").val();

// Here, I post it to a PHP file
// PHP file examines the data and returns result
// (in this case, if the postcode is covered or not)

$.post("scripts/postcode_handling.php", {postcode: postcode}, function(data) {

var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

// Check the coverage
if (result.coverage == true) {

// Do Something

} else {

// Do something

}
```

And on the php file I will do something like:

```
...
$result = array('coverage' => false , 'message' => "Your postcode is not covered")
echo json_encode($result);
....
```

I tried to do something similar in Rails by replacing the php file with an action under a controller, but I could not figure it out. Is this a common practice in Rails, and how can I do something like this?

Comment: Post what you tried in your rails controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use your post code example. Let's say you wanted to do an address lookup based on post code.

1. Create a route
2. Create a controller and an action to handle the request
3. Create the Javascript logic to handle sending the request and DOM manipulation

Open a `config/routes.rb` and add a route:

```
resources :address_lookups, only: :new
```

Create a controller to handle the route:

```
rails g controller AddressLookups
```

The above command creates a new controller called `address_lookups_controller.rb` inside `app/controllers`.

Now add the necessary logic inside the controller to handle the address lookup:

```
class AddressLookupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # This action will expect a params[:post_code] variable
    # that you will pass with your ajax request
    post_code = params[:post_code]
    address = FindSomeAddress.lookup(post_code)
    render json: address
  end
end
```

Now create a JavaScript handler to send the request and handle the return. If you generated the controller there should already be a file called `address_lookups.js.coffee` inside `app/assets/javascripts`. Here's some pseudo code.

```
jQuery ->

  $('#post_code').on 'blur', ->
    field = $(this)
    post_code = field.val()

    if post_code.length is 8
      xhr = $.ajax
        url: "/address_lookups/new"
        data:
          post_code: post_code
        success: (data) ->
          # do something with data
        dataType: "json"
```

Comment: maybe add `format: :json` to the route so it never tries to render html and can't find a view. Also for this I would use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked greatly. I ended up doing something like: `render html: 1 if PostcodeCoverage.exists?(:postcode => @postcode)` in the controller.

Comment: @MikeC you might want to use `render plain: "OK"` instead, since you are rendering a digit ("OK" can be anything you want). [Check out rendering here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text)